# Redirect subfolder to the main domain (root) using mod_rewrite (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, request

So I bought a script from the other guy (nothing fancy, let's say just a customized CMS) which is kinda complicated and uses frameworks that I don't know nothing about except names like "bootstrap", "laravel" and so. I am the guy who knows the basis and know some things from intermediate level but again, only some so when I see some fancy solutions I am getting confused.

Like here - I have never seen page built on files with strange extensions and *two* .htaccess files - one in root, and second in /public/ folder. Still, even though there are so many files, everything works really fine and fast.

Here is the issue's description:

So it seems that when browser loads the page (domain.com), it requests (I guess) content from /public/ folder and everything works fine and domain remains as domain.com. The thing is, that domain.com/public also works and I want to create redirection on this specific address just to prevent indexing this crappy-looking address of domain.com/public but bearing in mind, that domain.com should still work fine.

I have tried maaany solutions found here on SO and on other pages but they resulted in either crashing page (internal server error) or not doing anything at all. I think some of them might work but only when files are not embedded in another sub-folder. Eh I don't know, I am out of ideas. Can you please help me?

Here is the root's .httaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

And here is the public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like what you have should work, specifically the first condition + rule in the root `.htaccess` is meant to do what you're asking. I would polish it up a little:

In `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Fix URLs that begin with "public" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/public(?:/(\S*))?\s
RewriteRule ^ %1 [NS,NE,R=301,END]
# Internally rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^(?!public/).* public/$0 [DPI,L]
```

In `/public/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Pretend this is the root
    RewriteBase /
    # Redirect trailing slashes if not a folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [DPI,R=301,END]
    # Handle front controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$). index.php [DPI,END]
</IfModule>
```

You can use `L` instead of `END` if your version of Apache is old, you'll know because of a 500 error.

Comment: Thanks Walf for your willing to help. However your code didn't do anything, domain.com/public still loads and does not redirect to the domain.com... Do you know why?

Comment: You haven't said whether any other pages load. What happens if you put a line of nonsense random text at the beginning of your root `.htaccess`? If you don't get an error then, perhaps your rules aren't being used at all.